# Multiple thread working on same SparkContext concurrently gives unexpected result

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have developed a spark application with Kafka streaming & sql based on this [Spark example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/JavaSqlNetworkWordCount.java)

with 3 threads running different sql against the same SqlContext:

```
public final class TestSpark implements Serializable{
    private static final Pattern SPACE = Pattern.compile(" ");
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("TestSpark");
    private static ThreadFactory threadFactory = Executors.defaultThreadFactory();
    private static ExecutorService executorServices = new ThreadPoolExecutor(4, 8, 120, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(10000), threadFactory, new RejectedExecutionHandlerImpl());


  public TestSpark()
  {

  }

  public void run(String brokers, String topics, String master)
  {
    List<String> queryStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
    queryStrings.add("select id, type, key, side, shares, price, time, rank, flag, flag2, comment, source, status, price1, price2 from EventData where key in ('6267359')");
    queryStrings.add("select id, type, key, side, shares, price, time, rank, flag, flag2, comment, source, status, price1, price2 from EventData where key in ('6558484')");
    queryStrings.add("select id, type, key, side, shares, price, time, rank, flag, flag2, comment, source, status, price1, price2 from EventData where key in ('BP3R8Z3')");

    // Create context with 1 second batch interval
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TestSpark").setMaster("local[*]");
    JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(1));

    HashSet<String> topicsSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(topics.split(",")));
    HashMap<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
    kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list", brokers);

    // Create direct kafka stream with brokers and topics
    JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
        jssc,
        String.class,
        String.class,
        StringDecoder.class,
        StringDecoder.class,
        kafkaParams,
        topicsSet
    );

    JavaDStream<String> lines = messages.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {
        @Override
        public String call(Tuple2<String, String> tuple2) {
          return tuple2._2(); // We do not care about the key here
        }
      });

    lines.foreachRDD(new Function2<JavaRDD<String>, Time, Void>(){
        @Override
        public Void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd, Time time) throws Exception {
            if (!rdd.isEmpty())
            {
                SQLContext sqlContext = JavaSQLContextSingleton.getInstance(rdd.context()); 
                for (int i = 0; i < queryStrings.size(); i++)
                {
                    executorServices.execute(new ActionThread(sqlContext, rdd, queryStrings.get(i)));
                }               
            }
            return null;
        }

    });

    // Start the computation
    jssc.start();
    jssc.awaitTermination(); 
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 3) {
            System.err.println("Usage: DirectKafkaWordCount <brokers> <topics> <master>\n" +
                "  <brokers> is a list of one or more Kafka brokers\n" +
                "  <topics> is a list of one or more kafka topics to consume from\n" +
                "  <master> is spark cluster\n\n");
            System.exit(1);
          }


        TestSpark testSpark = new TestSpark();
        testSpark.run(args[0], args[1], args[2]);
  }
}

/** Lazily instantiated singleton instance of SQLContext */
class JavaSQLContextSingleton {
    static private transient SQLContext instance = null;
    static public SQLContext getInstance(SparkContext sparkContext) {
    if (instance == null) {
      instance = new SQLContext(sparkContext);
    }
    return instance;
  }
}

class ActionThread implements Serializable, Runnable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("ActionThread");
    SQLContext sqlContext;
    JavaRDD<String> rdd;
    String query;
    ActionThread(SQLContext sqlContext, JavaRDD<String> rdd, String query)
    {
        this.sqlContext = sqlContext;
        this.rdd = rdd;
        this.query = query;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        sqlContext.read().json(rdd).registerTempTable("EventData");
        DataFrame filteredEvent = sqlContext.sql(query);
        List<String> eventList = filteredEvent.toJavaRDD().map(new Function<Row, String>() {
            @Override
            public String call(Row row) 
            { 
                return "ThreadID:" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " " + row.toString();
            }
          }).collect();
        for (String event: eventList) {
            System.out.println(event);
        }
        filteredEvent.count();
    }
}

class RejectedExecutionHandlerImpl implements RejectedExecutionHandler {

    @Override
    public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
        System.out.println(r.toString() + " is rejected");
    }
}
```

However it's giving me unexpected results - I expect the first number in the Row to be unique but there are duplicates! I am sure they are unique by listening to the same topic.

```
ThreadID:109 [1,ORDER,6558484,SELL,1000000.0,7.26,2016-01-29T16:36:44.232+03:00,HIGH,Y,_NA_,LMT: Order in Hand,BOAML_AP,null,7.18,7.19]
ThreadID:107 [0,ORDER,6267359,SELL,1000000.0,7.26,2016-01-29T16:36:44.232+03:00,HIGH,Y,_NA_,LMT: Order in Hand,BOAML_AP,null,7.18,7.19]
ThreadID:75 [0,ORDER,6267359,SELL,1000000.0,7.26,2016-01-29T16:36:44.232+03:00,HIGH,Y,_NA_,LMT: Order in Hand,BOAML_AP,null,7.18,7.19]
ThreadID:75 [3,ORDER,6267359,SELL,1000000.0,7.26,2016-01-29T16:36:44.232+03:00,HIGH,Y,_NA_,LMT: Order in Hand,BOAML_AP,null,7.18,7.19]
ThreadID:107 [2,ORDER,BP3R8Z3,SELL,1000000.0,7.26,2016-01-29T16:36:44.232+03:00,HIGH,Y,_NA_,LMT: Order in Hand,BOAML_AP,null,7.18,7.19]
ThreadID:75 [3,ORDER,6267359,SELL,1000000.0,7.26,2016-01-29T16:36:44.232+03:00,HIGH,Y,_NA_,LMT: Order in Hand,BOAML_AP,null,7.18,7.19]
```

Does anyone have idea what is causing this or i should do it this way?

If i add a printline just below 'if (!rdd.isEmpty())' i got the following:

```
Rdd:MapPartitionsRDD[7] at map at TestSpark.java:111
Rdd:MapPartitionsRDD[9] at map at TestSpark.java:111
Rdd:MapPartitionsRDD[11] at map at TestSpark.java:111
Rdd:MapPartitionsRDD[21] at map at TestSpark.java:111
Rdd:MapPartitionsRDD[23] at map at TestSpark.java:111
Rdd:MapPartitionsRDD[25] at map at TestSpark.java:111
Rdd:MapPartitionsRDD[27] at map at TestSpark.java:111
Rdd:MapPartitionsRDD[29] at map at TestSpark.java:111
Rdd:MapPartitionsRDD[31] at map at TestSpark.java:111
Rdd:MapPartitionsRDD[33] at map at TestSpark.java:111
Rdd:MapPartitionsRDD[35] at map at TestSpark.java:111
ThreadID:75 [0,ORDER,6267359,SELL,1000000.0,7.26,2016-01-29T16:36:44.232+03:00,HIGH,Y,_NA_,LMT: Order in Hand,BOAML_AP,null,7.18,7.19]
ThreadID:92 [0,ORDER,6267359,SELL,1000000.0,7.26,2016-01-29T16:36:44.232+03:00,HIGH,Y,_NA_,LMT: Order in Hand,BOAML_AP,null,7.18,7.19]
Rdd:MapPartitionsRDD[37] at map at TestSpark.java:111
Rdd:MapPartitionsRDD[59] at map at TestSpark.java:111
Rdd:MapPartitionsRDD[61] at map at TestSpark.java:111
Rdd:MapPartitionsRDD[63] at map at TestSpark.java:111
Rdd:MapPartitionsRDD[97] at map at TestSpark.java:111
Rdd:MapPartitionsRDD[99] at map at TestSpark.java:111
ThreadID:75 [1,ORDER,6558484,SELL,1000000.0,7.26,2016-01-29T16:36:44.232+03:00,HIGH,Y,_NA_,LMT: Order in Hand,BOAML_AP,null,7.18,7.19]
Rdd:MapPartitionsRDD[124] at map at TestSpark.java:111
Rdd:MapPartitionsRDD[163] at map at TestSpark.java:111
Rdd:MapPartitionsRDD[187] at map at TestSpark.java:111
ThreadID:93 [3,ORDER,6267359,SELL,1000000.0,7.26,2016-01-29T16:36:44.232+03:00,HIGH,Y,_NA_,LMT: Order in Hand,BOAML_AP,null,7.18,7.19]
Rdd:MapPartitionsRDD[220] at map at TestSpark.java:111
```

Replace the println with System.out.println("Rdd.collect:" + rdd.collect()); i got the following so it looks like things are all good before threads. Perhaps i should just do it sequentially and let the cluster perform the filter in parallel..

```
    Rdd.collect:[{"id":0,"type":"ORDER","key":"6267359","key2":"BP3R8Z3","key3":null,"side":"SELL","shares":1000000.0,"price":7.26,"time":"2016-01-29T16:36:44.232+03:00","rank":"HIGH","flag":"Y","flag2":"_NA_","comment":"LMT: Order in Hand","others":"","others2":"","source":"BOAML_AP","status":null,"price1":7.18,"price2":7.19}, {"id":1,"type":"ORDER","key":"6558484","key2":"BP3R8Z3","key3":null,"side":"SELL","shares":1000000.0,"price":7.26,"time":"2016-01-29T16:36:44.232+03:00","rank":"HIGH","flag":"Y","flag2":"_NA_","comment":"LMT: Order in Hand","others":"","others2":"","source":"BOAML_AP","status":null,"price1":7.18,"price2":7.19}]
    Rdd.collect:[{"id":2,"type":"ORDER","key":"BP3R8Z3","key2":"BP3R8Z3","key3":null,"side":"SELL","shares":1000000.0,"price":7.26,"time":"2016-01-29T16:36:44.232+03:00","rank":"HIGH","flag":"Y","flag2":"_NA_","comment":"LMT: Order in Hand","others":"","others2":"","source":"BOAML_AP","status":null,"price1":7.18,"price2":7.19}]
    Rdd.collect:[{"id":3,"type":"ORDER","key":"6267359","key2":"BP3R8Z3","key3":null,"side":"SELL","shares":1000000.0,"price":7.26,"time":"2016-01-29T16:36:44.232+03:00","rank":"HIGH","flag":"Y","flag2":"_NA_","comment":"LMT: Order in Hand","others":"","others2":"","source":"BOAML_AP","status":null,"price1":7.18,"price2":7.19}]
    Rdd.collect:[{"id":4,"type":"ORDER","key":"6558484","key2":"BP3R8Z3","key3":null,"side":"SELL","shares":1000000.0,"price":7.26,"time":"2016-01-29T16:36:44.232+03:00","rank":"HIGH","flag":"Y","flag2":"_NA_","comment":"LMT: Order in Hand","others":"","others2":"","source":"BOAML_AP","status":null,"price1":7.18,"price2":7.19}]
    Rdd.collect:[{"id":5,"type":"ORDER","key":"BP3R8Z3","key2":"BP3R8Z3","key3":null,"side":"SELL","shares":1000000.0,"price":7.26,"time":"2016-01-29T16:36:44.232+03:00","rank":"HIGH","flag":"Y","flag2":"_NA_","comment":"LMT: Order in Hand","others":"","others2":"","source":"BOAML_AP","status":null,"price1":7.18,""price2":7.19}]
    Rdd.collect:[{"id":6,"type":"ORDER","key":"6267359","key2":"BP3R8Z3","key3":null,"side":"SELL","shares":1000000.0,"price":7.26,"time":"2016-01-29T16:36:44.232+03:00","rank":"HIGH","flag":"Y","flag2":"_NA_","comment":"LMT: Order in Hand","others":"","others2":"","source":"BOAML_AP","status":null,"price1":7.18,"price2":7.19}]
    Rdd.collect:[{"id":7,"type":"ORDER","key":"6558484","key2":"BP3R8Z3","key3":null,"side":"SELL","shares":1000000.0,"price":7.26,"time":"2016-01-29T16:36:44.232+03:00","rank":"HIGH","flag":"Y","flag2":"_NA_","comment":"LMT: Order in Hand","others":"","others2":"","source":"BOAML_AP","status":null,"price1":7.18,"price2":7.19}]
    Rdd.collect:[{"id":8,"type":"ORDER","key":"BP3R8Z3","key2":"BP3R8Z3","key3":null,"side":"SELL","shares":1000000.0,"price":7.26,"time":"2016-01-29T16:36:44.232+03:00","rank":"HIGH","flag":"Y","flag2":"_NA_","comment":"LMT: Order in Hand","others":"","others2":"","source":"BOAML_AP","status":null,"price1":7.18,"price2":7.19}]
    Rdd.collect:[{"id":9,"type":"ORDER","key":"6267359","key2":"BP3R8Z3","key3":null,"side":"SELL","shares":1000000.0,"price":7.26,"time":"2016-01-29T16:36:44.232+03:00","rank":"HIGH","flag":"Y","flag2":"_NA_","comment":"LMT: Order in Hand","others":"","others2":"","source":"BOAML_AP","status":null,"price1":7.18,""price2":7.19}]
    Rdd.collect:[{"id":10,"type":"ORDER","key":"6558484","key2":"BP3R8Z3","key3":null,"side":"SELL","shares":1000000.0,"price":7.26,"time":"2016-01-29T16:36:44.232+03:00","rank":"HIGH","flag":"Y","flag2":"_NA_","comment":"LMT: Order in Hand","others":"","others2":"","source":"BOAML_AP","status":null,"price1":7.18,"price2":7.19}]
    ThreadID:111 [1,ORDER,6558484,SELL,1000000.0,7.26,2016-01-29T16:36:44.232+03:00,HIGH,Y,_NA_,LMT: Order in Hand,BOAML_AP,null,7.18,7.19]
    ThreadID:75 [0,ORDER,6267359,SELL,1000000.0,7.26,2016-01-29T16:36:44.232+03:00,HIGH,Y,_NA_,LMT: Order in Hand,BOAML_AP,null,7.18,7.19]
    ThreadID:112 [0,ORDER,6267359,SELL,1000000.0,7.26,2016-01-29T16:36:44.232+03:00,HIGH,Y,_NA_,LMT: Order in Hand,BOAML_AP,null,7.18,7.19]
    Rdd.collect:[{"id":11,"type":"ORDER","key":"BP3R8Z3","key2":"BP3R8Z3","key3":null,"side":"SELL","shares":1000000.0,"price":7.26,"time":"2016-01-29T16:36:44.232+03:00","rank":"HIGH","flag":"Y","flag2":"_NA_","comment":"LMT: Order in Hand","others":"","others2":"","source":"BOAML_AP","status":null,"price1":7.18,"price2":7.19}}]
    Rdd.collect:[{"id":12,"type":"ORDER","key":"6267359","key2":"BP3R8Z3","key3":null,"side":"SELL","shares":1000000.0,"price":7.26,"time":"2016-01-29T16:36:44.232+03:00","rank":"HIGH","flag":"Y","flag2":"_NA_","comment":"LMT: Order in Hand","others":"","others2":"","source":"BOAML_AP","status":null,"price1":7.18,"price2":7.19}}]
    Rdd.collect:[{"id":13,"type":"ORDER","key":"6558484","key2":"BP3R8Z3","key3":null,"side":"SELL","shares":1000000.0,"price":7.26,"time":"2016-01-29T16:36:44.232+03:00","rank":"HIGH","flag":"Y","flag2":"_NA_","comment":"LMT: Order in Hand","others":"","others2":"","source":"BOAML_AP","status":null,"price1":7.18,"price2":7.19}}]
    Rdd.collect:[{"id":14,"type":"ORDER","key":"BP3R8Z3","key2":"BP3R8Z3","key3":null,"side":"SELL","shares":1000000.0,"price":7.26,"time":"2016-01-29T16:36:44.232+03:00","rank":"HIGH","flag":"Y","flag2":"_NA_","comment":"LMT: Order in Hand","others":"","others2":"","source":"BOAML_AP","status":null,"price1":7.18,"price2":7.19}}]
    ThreadID:111 [3,ORDER,6267359,SELL,1000000.0,7.26,2016-01-29T16:36:44.232+03:00,HIGH,Y,_NA_,LMT: Order in Hand,BOAML_AP,null,7.18,7.19]
    ThreadID:112 [2,ORDER,BP3R8Z3,SELL,1000000.0,7.26,2016-01-29T16:36:44.232+03:00,HIGH,Y,_NA_,LMT: Order in Hand,BOAML_AP,null,7.18,7.19]
    Rdd.collect:[{"id":15,"type":"ORDER","key":"6267359","key2":"BP3R8Z3","key3":null,"side":"SELL","shares":1000000.0,"price":7.26,"time":"2016-01-29T16:36:44.232+03:00","rank":"HIGH","flag":"Y","flag2":"_NA_","comment":"LMT: Order in Hand","others":"","others2":"","source":"BOAML_AP","status":null,"price1":7.18,"price2":7.19}}]
```

Comment: Why do you expect the first number to be unique? The included code is quite large, but does not give the full picture. What is in the data? What is in `queryStrings`? Which printout belongs to which iteration of `lines.foreachRDD`? Anyway, I think what you are missing is that if there are two `queryStrings` they will be executed on the same data. So they could easily return the same result.

Comment: The implementation is based on the example but i edited the post to include the whole program. The reason i expect it to be unique because I have a sender program to send those event with unique id, and i also have another listener which gets what got published. I suppose in each discrete micro-batch in the streaming, it should only contain what got published.

Comment: Also, the query criteria should capture everything. If my sender program is sending the events faster such that all events be captured in one duration which is 1 sec, there are no duplicates @Daniel Darabos

Comment: Thanks! I understand it better now. I don't think it's even about threads. Could you try to just print the RDD you get in `foreachRDD`? It looks like the same line is included in multiple RDDs. I've added the [spark-streaming] tag because I have no idea about how this works/is supposed to work.

Comment: Thanks. I got the following

Comment: Thanks   @DanielDarabos. I updated the question again with more details

Comment: Ah, okay, can you try printing `rdd.collect()` so that we see the contents of the RDD?

Comment: Not sure how to add a lot of stuff in comment, so i edited the original post again. THanks! @DanielDarabos

Comment: Thanks! It's very interesting. It looks like the RDDs are all good in `foreachRDD`, but then multiple threads with the same querystring (6267359) get the same RDD somehow. It's a good point that you don't really need threads. Spark will perform tasks in parallel anyway. But if you are not yet tired of debugging, I'd suggest logging `rdd.id()` inside the thread as well as when you do the `collect`. You could also try with just 1 querystring, and see if you still hit the issue.